# Is there a penalty for not stopping at marshal?

Tags: dirt-4

In the majority or rally games the stage ends after crossing the finish line, but in Dirt 4's rally events it is required to stop the car at the [marshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorsport_marshal). It is however possible to whiz through the marshal area at full speed, resulting in a completed race. This of course allows finishing tracks faster, but is there any penalty for doing so? And can the car get damaged after the game takes control?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there isn't any penalty for failing to stop at the marshal. If the fifteen second timer concludes then the race finishes with no penalty. I also discovered if your car is rendered inoperable (I finished one race on my car's roof) between the end of the race and the marshal's tent then the countdown will end early, still without penalty.

You can still heavily damage your car after the race finishes, in once case I rolled my vehicle and demolished the otherwise clean bodywork when the race's finish was at the end of a no-cut turn that I cut. Notably, I was still able to receive the clean racing bonus from my sponsor for an otherwise clean drive.

Comment: To confirm, you noted the [dirt-4] tag (the game may be considered as passé by now)? When you damaged your car after finishing, was the level of damage saved (if this wasn't only a single race)?

Comment: I'll confirm when I get back to Windows.